# How to show the dependent records that will be deleted before destroying a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Django admin shows you the dependent records that will be deleted when you delete a record as a confirmation.

Is there a way to do the same on Ruby on Rails?

I have been researching how to do it, but I am still looking for a way.

Comment: Haven't heard of anything like this, but doesn't look like a big job. You can get all the parent-children records if the relation is correctly set.

Comment: Sure, there are a few intuitive ways of doing it. 
Is there a gem or something that can be reused? May be a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a gem, so I wrote this concern using association reflections:

```rb
module DependentDestroys
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  DEPENDENT_DESTROY_ACTIONS = %i[destroy delete destroy_async]

  class_methods do
    def dependent_destroy_reflections
      @dependent_destroy_reflections ||= reflections.filter_map do |name, r|
        r if DEPENDENT_DESTROY_ACTIONS.include?(r.options[:dependent])
      end
    end
  end

  def total_dependent_destroys
    dependent_destroy_counts.sum { |r| r[1] }
  end

  def any_dependent_destroys?
    dependent_destroy_counts.any?
  end

  # If you want all affected records...
  def dependent_destroy_records
    self.class.dependent_destroy_reflections.flat_map do |r|
      relation = self.public_send(r.name)

      if r.collection?
        relation.find_each.to_a
      else
        relation
      end
    end
  end

  # If you only want the record type and ids...
  def dependent_destroy_ids
    self.class.dependent_destroy_reflections.flat_map do |r|
      relation = self.public_send(r.name)

      if r.collection?
        relation.pluck(:id).map { |rid| [r.klass, rid] }
      else
        [[r.klass, relation.id]] if relation
      end
    end.compact
  end

  # If you only want counts...
  def dependent_destroy_counts
    self.class.dependent_destroy_reflections.filter_map do |r|
      relation = self.public_send(r.name)

      if r.collection?
        c = relation.count
        [r.klass, c] if c.positive?
      else
        [r.klass, 1] if relation
      end
    end
  end

  def dependent_destroy_total_message
    "#{total_dependent_destroys} associated records will be destroyed"
  end

  def dependent_destroy_message
    # Using #human means you can define model names in your translations.
    "The following dependent records will be destroyed: #{dependent_destroy_ids.map { |r| "#{r[0].model_name.human}/#{r[1]}" }.join(', ')}"
  end

  def dependent_destroy_count_message
    "The following dependent records will be destroyed: #{dependent_destroy_counts.map { |r| "#{r[0].model_name.human(count: r[1])} (#{r[1]})" }.join(', ')}"
  end
end
```

Usage:

```rb
class User
  include DependentDestroys

  belongs_to :company
  has_many :notes
  has_one :profile
end

user = User.first

user.any_dependent_destroys?
# => true

user.total_dependent_destroys
# => 60

user.dependent_destroy_total_message
# => "60 associated records will be destroyed"

user.dependent_destroy_message
# => "The following dependent records will be destroyed: Note/1, Note/2, ..., Profile/1"

user.dependent_destroy_count_message
# => "The following dependent records will be destroyed: Notes (59), Profile (1)"
```

You can then use these methods in the controller to deal with the user flow.

With some improvements, options (like limiting it to the associations or modes (destroy, delete, destroy_async) you want) and tests, this could become a gem.